# Why isn't block the row?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to block a row, but I would like to block to avoid to be update while I am using it, but I would like to let select the row. So I think that a UPDLOCK it would be a good option instead of serializable isolation level because it would block the reads too. So I am trying to use this query to test:

```
begin tran
select ID from MyTable with(UPLDOCK);
rollback
```

I run this query in one SSMS and in a second SSMS, but in the second SMSS is not blocked.

If I use a select * then it is blocked, but I would like to block when I get only the fields that I need.

So my question is, would it be possible to block the row only for updates and deletes (like UPDLOCK does) but getting only the fields that I need?

Thanks.

Comment: If the second query uses `updlock` too, it will be blocked.

Comment: For me it works fine using "Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-GDR) (KB3194714) - 12.0.5203.0 (X64)   Sep 23 2016 18:13:56   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) ". So, it blocks the rows even if I select only ID and try in another window to run the UPDATE before to run the ROLLBACK line in the main window.

Comment: Why? If this is to generate an auto id, either use an identity or a sequence.